# Search for image and popup message if found

Tags: imacros

I am struggling finding out a way to search for an image called checked.bmp and when its found to popup a message or extract it to the excel. If not found then will follow to the next record.

I used this line but didn't work for me

SEARCH SOURCE=TXT:"/NEW/test/images/unchecked.bmp" extract=TXT

Comment: can you give some imacros code? if possible an example website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys but i found the solution for my case

SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"/checked.bmp" EXTRACT=FOUND

Answer (score 0):

This finds the first occurrence of img tag with path that contains 'images/checked.bmp' and saves the url to the !EXTRACT variable.
Second line is to add the curren page's url to the same variable and the third one saves the data into 'data.csv' file in the default imacros folder.

```
TAG XPATH=".//body/descendant::img[contains(@src,'images/checked.bmp')][1]" EXTRACT=HREF
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=data.csv
```

The result is csv table with two columns.
Also a lot of relevant info could be found here: http://wiki.imacros.net/Data_Extraction